# Question about rotate bitmap with Canvas.rotate

Tags: android

As we know, we can rotate a bitmap through 2 ways.

**The 1st way is:**

```
Matrix mt = new Matrix(); 
mt.postRotate(degree); 
Bitmap bitmap = CreateBitmap(src, 0, 0, w, h, mt, true); 
canvs.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
```

In this way, we always need create new bitmap for every rotation, it is not good way for high performance game or app.

**The 2nd way is:**

```
canvas.save(); 
canvas.rotate(degree); 
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint); 
canvas.restore();
```

In this way, we avoid creating new bitmap frequently, but the rotation bitmap is distortion, the bitmap quality is worse than first way.

So, Is there 3rd way to rotate bitmap with high performance and good quality?

Your any comments are really appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you providing `Paint` to `canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint)`.

And don't forget to use anti-alias and bitmap filtering:

```
paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want high speed graphical applications (even 2D) you should use OpenGL on Android.

I believe Replica Island uses OpenGL and VBO's (where available) for rendering it's 2D scene. But I can't find a reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've think about GL before but I don't want to use it since my app is not a game just a application.

Answer (score 0):

this method should use the GPU to rotate the bitmap

[Canvas.drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap, android.graphics.Matrix, android.graphics.Paint)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Matrix,%20android.graphics.Paint))